# A line of Ruby code, which I don't understand, is giving me a mass-assignment error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm currently reading Rails 3 In Action.  The book creates an app where one can create Projects and for each Project on can create Tickets.  It creates 3 models:

Project:

```
    class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :name
      validates :name, presence: true
      has_many :tickets, :dependent => :destroy
    end
```

Ticket:

```
    class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :project
      belongs_to :user
      attr_accessible :description, :title
      validates :title, presence: true
      validates :description, presence: true, :length => { :minimum => 10 }
    end
```

and User:

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
      attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
    end
```

Now when I add the following line to the create action inside the tickets_controller:

```
    @ticket = @project.tickets.build(params[:ticket].merge!(:user => current_user))
```

I get this error `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: user`.  Now I don't really understand what merge! is doing and why :user is being passed in or why I'm getting the error.  I know that normally I would have to include the mass-assignment attribute to the attr_accessible: method.  But this time the attribute is a class so I don't know how to handle this.

help,
mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ticket = @project.tickets.build(params[:ticket])
@ticket.user = current_user
```

Unless there's a reason why you need this on a single line? In which case maybe

```
@ticket = @project.tickets.build(params[:ticket].merge!(:user_id => current_user.id))
```

Comment: Thanx Pasted, that works (the 2 line solution).  But I have one more question.  Inside Ticket I have `belongs_to :project` and `belongs_to :user`.  Then inside Project I have a corresponding `has_many :tickets` but inside User there is no corresponding `has_many :tickets` is this an oversight on the book's part?  I know this edition has many typographical errors in it.

Comment: The User model looks like it's the default model generated by Devise - which doesn't include any associations. Not sure if you can specify any associations in the generator but I generally just add these to the User model later.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to your Ticket model should work. You have to specify what nested attributes to accept for to use in a single form.

```
attr_accessible :description, :title, :user     
accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html